# script external link into a js file

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me to "convert" a external js script from a html page into a script in a .js file??
I have a countdown script, and a part of it is with these external link and i don't like it, can i put him into a js fie ??

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var endDate = "June 7, 2087 15:03:25";

    $('.countdown.simple').countdown({ date: endDate });

    $('.countdown.styled').countdown({
      date: endDate,
      render: function(data) {
        $(this.el).html("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.years, 4) + " <span>years</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 3) + " <span>days</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span>hrs</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>min</span></div><div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>sec</span></div>");
      }
    });

    $('.countdown.callback').countdown({
      date: +(new Date) + 10000,
      render: function(data) {
        $(this.el).text(this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " sec");
      },
      onEnd: function() {
        $(this.el).addClass('ended');
      }
    }).on("click", function() {
      $(this).removeClass('ended').data('countdown').update(+(new Date) + 10000).start();
    });

    // End time for diff purposes
    var endTimeDiff = new Date().getTime() + 15000;
    // This is server's time
    var timeThere = new Date();
    // This is client's time (delayed)
    var timeHere = new Date(timeThere.getTime() - 5434);
    // Get the difference between client time and server time
    var diff_ms = timeHere.getTime() - timeThere.getTime();
    // Get the rounded difference in seconds
    var diff_s = diff_ms / 1000 | 0;

    var notice = [];
    notice.push('Server time: ' + timeThere.toDateString() + ' ' + timeThere.toTimeString());
    notice.push('Your time: ' + timeHere.toDateString() + ' ' + timeHere.toTimeString());
    notice.push('Time difference: ' + diff_s + ' seconds (' + diff_ms + ' milliseconds to be precise). Your time is a bit behind.');

    $('.offset-notice').html(notice.join('<br />'));

    $('.offset-server .countdown').countdown({
      date: endTimeDiff,
      offset: diff_s * 1000,
      onEnd: function() {
        $(this.el).addClass('ended');
      }
    });

    $('.offset-client .countdown').countdown({
      date: endTimeDiff,
      onEnd: function() {
        $(this.el).addClass('ended');
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

There is the code.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#A_.22hello_world.22_example

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Create a new file and call it countdown.js and place it in the same folder as your html file.

Then from inside your html page add

```
<script src="countdown.js"></script>
```